# Failed to create appdomain "master.sys[runtime].2"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory, standard-edition

I am getting this error in SQL Server log:

> Failed to create appdomain "master.sys[runtime].2"
> Could not load file or assembly System.Data.
> Not enough storage is available to process this command

After this error, my web application is not working.

Following are the server specs:

- SQL Version : **SQL 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 Intel(x86) Standard Edition**
- RAM : **64 GB** (Max Memory: 2147483647)
- Hard Disk Memory Size Available : **600 GB**
- Effective memory in use by instance:

  1. physical_memory_in_use_Gb : 2.94
  2. locked_page_allocations_Gb: 0
  3. virtual_address_space_committed_Gb: 2.98

I have searched on this. But not got any proper solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I finally understand why your server uses only `3Gb` of RAM, you have `32-bit` version of SQL Server: SQL 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 Intel(**x86**) and it just cannot use more than `4Gb`.

You should use 64-bit version of the Server to resolve your problem.

In previous versions (until 2012) it seems `-g` parameter could be useful:
[SQL Server 2012 Memory](https://mssqlwiki.com/2012/10/21/sql-server-2012-memory-2/)

> -g startup parameter
>
> We used the -g startup option to change the default value of a region
>   in SQL Server user address space known as "Memory-To-Reserve". This
>   region was also known as "memory-to-leave or MTL.  The
>   "Memory-To-Reserve" (or) -g configuration option are relevant only for
>   a 32-bit instance of SQL Server.
>
> Multi pages allocation and CLR was part of Mem-to-reserve (-g)  in In
>   previous SQL Server versions until SQL Server 2008 R2 , From Denali
>   they are part of BPOOL (Controlled by Max server memory)  So you may
>   have to remove –g if you have set it to give space for multipage
>   allocator or CLR in earlier versions and migrating to Denali now.

But since you are on `2012` it seems the only way is to install `SQL Server x64`

Comment: @Pravin - if this answer worked for you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting SQL server. It helped me.